# What code to use to see how long Unix took to run a blastn

Tags: bioinformatics

I have just run the following foreach:

```bsh
for file in *.fa
do
  echo working on $file !
  blastn -db ../lotus-date -query $file > $file.blastn
  echo finished $file
done
```

Is there a way to deduce how long this code took to run after it is completed?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the approximate time you started the script you could compare that to the last modification time of the output file written by the last iteration through the loop.

Look at the last line of this command to see the date/time of the most recently modified `blastn` output file

```
ls -ltr *.fa.blastn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current UNIX time in seconds at the start of your script with `date +%s`, then print to `stdout` the difference between that and the time at the end of your script:

```bsh
start="$( date +%s )"

for file in *.fa
do
  echo working on $file !
  blastn -db ../lotus-date -query $file > $file.blastn
  echo finished $file
done

printf '%s\n' "Code took $(( $( date +%s ) - $start )) seconds to run."
```